# Parse JSON array data in android using Volley

Tags: android-volley, android-json

**JSON data format:**
I am trying to fetch this array json data but not getting it.

```
[{"Items":"Chicken Burger","Price":"250","Quantity":"2"}, 
{"Items":"Hamburger","Price":"230","Quantity":"3"}]
```

**MyCartActivity class:**
I tried using Volley and I am now getting that JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject error. Can you mention where to change so that I can get my data?

```
 final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest (Request.Method.POST, fetchurl, null, new  Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {

                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("");

                for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String Price = object.getString("Price");
                    String Name = object.getString("Items");
                    String Quantity = object.getString("Quantity");

                    adapter = new CartAdapter(MyCartActivity.this, list);
                    list.add(new CartPojo(Price, Name, Quantity));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

     requestQueue.add(request);
  }
```

**Adapter class:**

```
    public CartAdapter(Activity activity, List datalist) {

    this.activity = activity;
    this.datalist = datalist;
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
   return datalist.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return datalist.get(position);
 }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_item_layout, null);

    TextView ItemName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    TextView Price = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
    TextView Quantity = convertView.findViewById(R.id.items_quantity);

    CartPojo pojo = datalist.get(position);

    ItemName.setText(String.valueOf(pojo.getName()));
    Price.setText(String.valueOf(pojo.getPrice()));
    Quantity.setText(String.valueOf(pojo.getQuantity()));

    return convertView;
  }
```

Please provide me some solutions....

Answer (score 0):

The response can't be parsed into `JSONObject`, because its not that, but a `JSONArray`. You can send a simple `StringRequest` and then parse the response string into an `JSONArray` using `JSONArray(response)` constructor.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
});
```

Or use the `JsonArrayRequest`. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/cblunt/162beb7ecfafa1bd2ad9) an example.

Comment: Thank you @Andrej I'll check out using this

Comment: I have changed JsonObjectRequest to StringRequest as you mentioned about it but still no changes for the process of fetching data. It is showing Frames are Skipped... what can be the reason behind this....

Comment: Do I have to make some changes over Adpater class also? please let me know where should I have to make those changes....

Comment: Frames are skipped because you are doing too much processing on the main thread. Take a look at threading in Android. Do you get a response with a stringRequest?

Comment: No I didn't get any response

Comment: Maybe your URL is not valid. Try validating the request you are sending with a Postman plugin for Chrome to see if you have a valid URL and parameters.

Comment: Is there any problem with the rest of the codes of MyCartActivity and Adapter class?

Comment: First you should solve the problem with not getting the response from the request, then you will see if the rest of the code works.

Comment: There is no problem with url, "http://192.168.0.105/testing/select.php", you can also check it...

Comment: It's running on localhost, only you can check it. If you open it in browser, do you get the same JSON as in the question? Also you are making a POST request. If you are only retrievieng data you should use GET.

Comment: Yes I am getting the same... I tried using both GET and POST but no any changes...please help me to get rid out of it... as I am new in programming so I also do not have much more deep knowledge about each and every codes. Are you sure there is no connection with other codes that let such errors? If there are some errors then please let me know!

Comment: Which type of a request did you specify for that path on API side (I guess in your php script)?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand...?

Comment: You mean to say StringRequest or JSONArray request...?